PHP session variables lost - sometimes
My session variables disappear about 1 in 10 times and I don't understand why.
I have 2 scripts one which is called when the page is loaded: a.php. It initializes the session variables and the session below.
a.php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
  $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
  $_SESSION['lives'] = 5;
....

when the user clicks something a second php script is run: b.php. It has the exact same beginning, except this time the logical statement should be false, so the if statement should not be entered.
b.php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
  echo "Something is wrong!"
....

For some reason about 1 in every 10 times I reload the page, the session variables are deleted between the first and the second script and the if statement in b.php is entered and I don't understand why.
I am using PHPstorm as an IDE and testing on localhost could it be some configuration issue with PHPstorm or my local php server?

I'm not comfortable with the: ?>, then a new line, and then: <?php, between the header and session start. It's not needed and the new line character is basically outputted to the browser. Since session_start() should be run before any other output, I am amazed it works at all? Perhaps you didn't test this specific code?

The point is that you have a rather weird problem, and the best way to find out what could cause it is to try and reproduce it somehow. With the current code in your question we can't do that.

@KIKOSoftware "and the new line character is basically outputted to the browser" - I don't think it actually is, in this particular instance. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php: "[...] when the PHP interpreter hits the ?> closing tags, it simply starts outputting whatever it finds (except for the immediately following newline - see instruction separation)" - and https://3v4l.org/vEVI0 also appears to confirm.

@CBroe Ah, PHP is smarter than I thought. Good to know. This still leaves the problem of having incomplete code examples. Reproduction of the problem is probably hard anyway, so maybe a similar question can help? Running the first PHP 7 version could also be a problem? Maybe? I don't know, this is a difficult problem for sure.

thanks I also think it doesn't make a difference but got rid of the ?> <?php and I still got the same error. I am using PHP 8.1.
I agree reproduction can be tricky, but I don't think more complete code would be helpful. The Php scripts only set the session variables and dont do much more.

It could be something in the environment of the server. Anything that's not a simple web server with a static IP address could cause problems. You could check the session id, it shouldn't change, and with browser developer tools you can keep an eye on the session cookie, it shouldn't expire and stay the same.

'I agree reproduction can be tricky, but I don't think more complete code would be helpful.' at this state not, but if you remove the rest of the code, does the problem still arise? This would be a pointer that the culprit is in those parts...

Figured it out. The culprit was phpstorm. It worked using a different php server
